# Can we set cookies from cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

Can we set cookies to a viewer request by an edge lambda in a cloudfront and redirect to the same page?

I have given a sample code below written for edge lambda. Same code accepts for the Origin Request in the cloudfront events, but rejected by viewer request.

> Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidLambdaFunctionAssociation;
>   Request ID:xx

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
     var date = new Date();

     // Get Unix milliseconds at current time plus 365 days
     date.setTime(+ date + (365 * 86400000)); //24 \* 60 \* 60 \* 100
     var cookieVal = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7); // Generate a random cookie string

     var cookieString = "testCookie="+cookieVal+"; domain=dxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net; path=/index.html; expires="+date.toGMTString()+";";

    const response = {
        status: '302',
        statusDescription: 'Found',
        headers: {
            location: [{
            key: 'Location',
            value: 'https://dxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/index.html',
            }],
            'set-cookie': [{
                key: 'Set-Cookie',
                value: cookieString
            }],
        },
    };
    callback(null, response);
};
```

Scenario: Setting cookies in the login page, if cookies are not set, set cookies to the login page with a redirection

Comment: Let's clarify: you get this error when you try to *configure* the Cache Behavior to use this Lambda function -- not when you try to access the site -- correct?  Are you able to associate it from the Lambda console by creating a trigger? (Or is that what you're doing, here?)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I am trying to associate lambda with the viewer request event. Yes, user scenario is about, setting cookies to the login page and then authenticate and give access to home page.

For now login page is in the s3 bucket, so just want to set cookie in the viewer request in cloudfront and redirect to login with cookies if cookies are not set.

Comment: @LakinduGunasekara Did you check this post and fix the permissions to your lambda. Looks like cloudfront cannot invoke the lambda  causing the error. Also make sure lambda-runtime is lambda edge and not regular runtime.

Comment: The likely culprit of this error is that you are trying to make a lambda function association to a lambda that is deployed in a region *other* than us-east-1. Lambda edge functions *must* be deployed in us-east-1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-requirements-limits.html#lambda-requirements-cloudfront-triggers